# Yahoo messenger IM logs

Tags: logging, yahoo-messenger

I would just like to ask, does yahoo messenger saves im logs to my computer locally?
If so, where can I find it?
Or it is saved online to yahoo servers and nothing is saved locally?

Answer (score 1):

They are safed local on your computer On the Yahoo-Messenger-Help website, there is a nice tutorial:

> 1. Select *My Computer*.
> 2. Select *Local Disk (C:)*.
> 3. Select the *Program Files* folder.
> 4. Select the *Yahoo* folder.
> 5. Select the *Messenger* folder.
> 6. Select the *Logs* folder.
>
> You should now see the requested log files, although they may appear
>   without extensions (.log) if your computer is set to hide extensions.
>   To show extensions to ensure you have the proper files:
>
> 1. Click on *Tools*, then click *Folder Options*.
> 2. Click the *View* tab.
> 3. Uncheck *Hide extensions for known file types*.
> 4. Click *Apply*, then click *OK*.

[Source](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_MSNG&id=SLN178&impressions=false)